# How do I transfer DLC Packs from one PS3 to another?

Tags: ps3, psn

A while ago I got a couple of DLC Map Packs for Black Ops 1. I recenntly by given a new PS3 because the old has trouble spinning a disk. I had someone help me do a save data transfer but it didn't carry over the DLCs. How to I redownload them to the new PS3 without deactivating my previous PS3's psn account for myself?

Comment: pretty sure you have to deactivate your PSN account, this is the only way sony can be sure you are not ripping them off

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is activate your new ps3 with your psn account. You can have up to 2 active ps3's per account, for cases like this is the thought behind it. Once you activate the ps3 with the account you can redownload your dlc's through the playstation store with no problem at all. So as long as you didn't give a friend's ps3 access to your account you will be AOK. If you did then you can force deactivate all ps3's or a selected one on your account through the SONY site or ask your friend to deactivate your account on their ps3. I did this once they restricted the number of active ps3's to 2.

Answer (score 0):

the only option to do this is to sign in to your existing account with the new PS3. If you shared that account with somebody else, you will **HAVE TO** deactivate the account from your old PS3 or ask your friend to deactivate your account from his/her PS3

Answer (score -2):

U can deactivate all your ps3, and activate your new ps3 every 6 months using your a cell phone, Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi Lucky! While this is an answer, it lacking a ton of information to help OP or anyone else that would have this same question.  What would be helpful would be more information as to how using a cell phone works in moving that DLC over.